# Spring mvc annotation config. Error 404 when upgrade to spring 4.3.9

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

My java spring mvc project is in 4.0.6.RELEASE spring version Project loads home page at http://localhost:8080/. When I change to newer 4.3.9.RELEASE in pom.xml I get error 404 tomcat page.

I use tomcat Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22, IntelliJ, windows10, chrome (but edge shows 404 too). I've tried to rebuild project, refresh maven, but it didn't work.

I've attached config files and folder structure. I'm hope that it's not too much code. Thanks for all help.

AppConfig

```
/** imports */

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.websystique.springmvc")
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}
}
```

AppController

```
/** imports */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {

@Autowired
QuestionService service;

@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

@Autowired
PointsCounter pointsCounter;

private List<Answer> answerList;

/**
 * Load home page
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String mainPage(ModelMap modelMap) {
    return "home";
}

/** More methods (...)
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>websystique</groupId>
<artifactId>websystique</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
    <testng.version>6.9.4</testng.version>
    <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.187</h2.version>
    <dbunit.version>2.2</dbunit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jsr303 validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Joda-Time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Testing dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${h2.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>SpringHibernateExample</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <finalName>SpringHibernateExample</finalName>
</build>
```

[My folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRxI1.png)

edit---------
My server log (IntelliJ) - Spring 4.3.9 - error 404

```
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\catalina.bat" 
run
[2017-08-16 01:30:24,219] Artifact questions-websystique:war exploded: 
Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Max\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_websystique_20"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 

9.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.867 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 21 2017 09:44:18 UTC
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.0.0
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.868 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Max\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_websystique_20
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Max\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_websystique_20\conf\logging.properties
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.870 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Max\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_websystique_20
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.870 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.870 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.870 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3190200;;.]
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.981 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.995 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
16-Aug-2017 01:30:24.998 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
16-Aug-2017 01:30:25.000 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
16-Aug-2017 01:30:25.000 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 367 ms
16-Aug-2017 01:30:25.028 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
16-Aug-2017 01:30:25.028 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22
16-Aug-2017 01:30:25.035 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
16-Aug-2017 01:30:25.041 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
16-Aug-2017 01:30:25.044 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 43 ms
Connected to server
[2017-08-16 01:30:25,320] Artifact questions-websystique:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
16-Aug-2017 01:30:27.073 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2017-08-16 01:30:27,114] Artifact questions-websystique:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-08-16 01:30:27,114] Artifact questions-websystique:war exploded: Deploy took 1 794 milliseconds
16-Aug-2017 01:30:35.036 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
16-Aug-2017 01:30:35.062 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [25] ms
```

Chrome shows this:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message /

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22
```

This is log from working version - spring 4.0.6.RELEASE

```
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2017-08-16 07:29:01,446] Artifact questions-websystique:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Max\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_websystique_20"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.908 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.909 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 21 2017 09:44:18 UTC
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.909 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.0.0
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.909 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Max\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_websystique_20
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Max\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_websystique_20\conf\logging.properties
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.911 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.911 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Max\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_websystique_20
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.911 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.911 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.911 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3190200;;.]
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.980 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.993 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.994 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.996 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
16-Aug-2017 19:29:01.996 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 256 ms
16-Aug-2017 19:29:02.016 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
16-Aug-2017 19:29:02.016 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22
16-Aug-2017 19:29:02.021 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
16-Aug-2017 19:29:02.027 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
16-Aug-2017 19:29:02.028 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 32 ms
Connected to server
[2017-08-16 07:29:02,475] Artifact questions-websystique:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
16-Aug-2017 19:29:03.341 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
16-Aug-2017 19:29:03.420 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
16-Aug-2017 19:29:03.482 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Aug 16 19:29:03 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
16-Aug-2017 19:29:03.537 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions Registering annotated classes: [class com.websystique.springmvc.configuration.AppConfig]
16-Aug-2017 19:29:04.001 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
16-Aug-2017 19:29:04.137 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
16-Aug-2017 19:29:04.143 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
16-Aug-2017 19:29:04.146 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
16-Aug-2017 19:29:04.148 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
16-Aug-2017 19:29:04.463 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
16-Aug-2017 19:29:04.588 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator.initiateService HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
16-Aug-2017 19:29:04.593 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.<init> HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
16-Aug-2017 19:29:04.824 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@2d15b144] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
16-Aug-2017 19:29:04.972 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod Mapped "{[//],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.websystique.springmvc.controller.AppController.mainPage(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
16-Aug-2017 19:29:04.972 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod Mapped "{[//processForm],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.websystique.springmvc.controller.AppController.processAnswers(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)
16-Aug-2017 19:29:04.973 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod Mapped "{[//questionlist],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.websystique.springmvc.controller.AppController.showQuestionList()
16-Aug-2017 19:29:05.027 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1607 ms
16-Aug-2017 19:29:05.034 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
16-Aug-2017 19:29:05.037 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Aug 16 19:29:05 CEST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
16-Aug-2017 19:29:05.056 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 22 ms
[2017-08-16 07:29:05,066] Artifact questions-websystique:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-08-16 07:29:05,066] Artifact questions-websystique:war exploded: Deploy took 2 591 milliseconds
16-Aug-2017 19:29:12.022 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
16-Aug-2017 19:29:12.041 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [18] ms
```

Comment: You have a final name in you pom file _SpringHibernateExample_ so I guess the url should be localhost:8080/SpringHibernateExample. How are you deploying the application to tomcat?

Comment: I've added tomcat server/local, added "war exploded" artifact, apply, ok, and then green play/run button in IntelliJ.
localhost:8080/SpringHibernateExample show 404 too,
with 4.0.6.RELEASE spring home page was at localhost:8080

Comment: What happens when you add another `/` at the end of the URL ?

Comment: localhost:8080/ shows error 404 too, adding http:// does nothing too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I didn't have taglibs in 2 of 3 my .jsp files. I've added this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE somehow works without them.

Answer (score 0):

You have already mapped `/` on class level so you don't need to map it again on method level. You doing so means trying to access a resource on `//` which is not just possible. This is because the map on method is relative to that on class.

So just replace `@RequestMapping(value = "/")` on mainPage method of your controller class with just

```
@RequestMapping
```

Or with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "")
```

Or with

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately I still get error 404

Comment: Please post your server log

Comment: I've added logs. I've also tried to reinstall Tomcat, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hope your `home.jsp` is in `/WEB-INF/views/' ?

Comment: Yes, I posted link to my folder tree in main post, jsp files are in that directory.
I've got some more detailed logs from tomcat now (not working version):[link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/feb365e725275dc61e5d6c62e509e40c), last lines print something about folder which does not exist: `org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanResourcePaths No TLD files were found in resource path [/WEB-INF/jsp/].` i think this could be important

Comment: Access this url on your browser let see if it will work `localhost:8080/SpringHibernateExample/`

Comment: `localhost:8080/SpringHibernateExample/` doesn't work - still error 404

Comment: Hope your `AppController` is no longer as posted?  It should be as I earlier corrected before trying that out?

Comment: Yes, I tested project with all 3 options. Currently my mainPage method is with 1st option (@RequestMapping). Project still works when I change spring version in pom.xml back to 4.0.6.RELEASE, but doesn't work at higher versions 4.3.9.RELEASE or 4.3.10.RELEASE